# Is there an alternative to the rugarch package for GARCH modelling?

Tags: programming, garch

I have been trying to use the rugarch package but I find it sometimes limiting. After certain amount of data points the package doesn't converge and it becomes kind of annoying. Is there any R/Python/Matlab alternative to it? I am trying to fit an apARCH model but it seems like there are not too many options. I also thought about using fGarch, but it also has some disadvantages.

Comment: With respect to the rugarch package, have you tried setting the solver method to *'hybrid'*, eg. *solver = hybrid*? Other than that, you can work with the solver control to try and establish convergence, eg. *solver.control = list(tol = 1e-12)*, gives you a smaller tolerance for the solver? Sometimes the solver fails to converge due to bad initial values? Maybe some of these tips will help you out? :-)

Comment: I tried using the method _hybrid_. I'll check the tolerance of the solver. I'll give it a try. I also tried optimizing the parameters with the fGarch package and using them as "fixed" parameters on rugarch, but it was hopeless.

Comment: I found an alternative on Python, but it still has the nuisance that modelling the mean is not very straightforward. It is particularly a problem if you want to use ARFIMA modelling for the mean. My take on this: package is a good option but right now it is quite limited. More information can be found [here](https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/introduction.html)

Comment: Save yourself the headache and write the code yourself. If you walk into problems, ask the question on stackoverflow ;).